# jQuery hashchange #summary issue

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins

Background;

I have a javascript application that uses jQuery and specifically the hashchange 
plugin (http://plugins.jquery.com/project/hashchange). The application is 
"controlled" by the hash value in the browser - i.e. when the hash changes the
application is notified and changes state accordingly.

The application is used to fill out forms. So the user steps through 
all the pages of the form and lastly, before the form can be submitted, he
sees a "summary" page i.e. a page containing all the form fields and entered 
values. Stepping through the form pages the hash changes like #0, #1, #2 and
so on (depending on the number of pages in the actual form, of course). The summary 
page is called #summary.

Now this works perfectly on almost all platforms and browsers. However, when 
running on IE8 on Windows XP SP3 - a problem arises:

It seems like whenever the hash part of the url changes to "#summary" the 
hash change event is not fired.

This has been verified with breakpoints in the handler code. Where form pages
triggers normally, with the summary page nothing happens. As said, on all other 
OS and browser configurations this works fine.

I basically have two ideas to try out, but neither can be done without some
development effort (which is a scarce resource on the project).

1. Try another hash change plugin. It seems hashchange is taken from the "history"
   plugin. So maybe I could try that one - or maybe there are other suggestions?
2. Change the name of the summary page to something else, e.g. #verification.

Both of these sounds a bit desparate, hence this post. Comments or suggestion are
very welcome.

Thanks in advance,
Mads

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the easiest way would be to just change the name of the page but if you do insist on keeping the name I can suggest two different plugins.

First [DavisJS](http://davisjs.com/) with the [hash routing extension](https://github.com/olivernn/davis.js/blob/master/src/extensions/davis.hashRouting.js) Is something that I have used and been recomended several times.

There is also Ben Cherry's [Saner HTML5 History App](http://www.bcherry.net/playground/sanerhtml5history) which is a slightly lighter weight library and not a whole client side routing framework like davis.